# How to add an entry to a context menu in Windows 7 and associate a complicated command to it?

Tags: windows-7, registry, contextmenu, pipe, regedit

E.g. when I right-click any directory I want to have an option which executes the following:

```
svn info | grep URL | awk "{print $NF}"
```

or any other command consisting of pipes or other compilcated stuff (the above command gets the URL of SVN repository but this is just an example).

What I've tried to do is to add a new key in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell, add a key called command to it and set its default value to the above command. Unfortunately it just doesn't work that way. Any ideas?

Comment: Pipes are interpreted by cmd.exe, so you will have to pump the command through cmd first.

Comment: Good point but how do I do that?

Comment: I thought I said that already. Use cmd.exe.

Comment: Could you give an example, please?

Comment: I still don't know what to type in the registry. Anything more complicated I try just doesn't work.

Comment: You need to share with the group what you tried. We're not psychic.